# android scale ImageView parent clip scaled imageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

i have imageView inside `LinearLayout` the imageView scaled  by

```
 setScaleX(e);
 setScaleY(e);
```

> e  is float value

and the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">




    <test.blabla.com.app.scledImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
         android:id="@+id/scaled"
        android:src="@drawable/emoji_1f3b0_64"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />




  </LinearLayout>
```

now this image before i scale ImageView

[image]

after scale imageView

[image]

the parent LinearLayout not effected by scale and its height and width still same
i try use this for linearLayout while scale

```
parent.invalidate();
```

also i tried

```
parent. postInvalidate();
```

still same problem

Comment: why don't you use scaleType property of ImageView to scale image automatically?

Comment: @AndroidGeek i want to scale it while press an  button

Comment: share your activity code also

Comment: activity code too long and its not related to the problem :/

Comment: change your view `LayoutParams`, calling `setScale*` will not change them

Comment: @pskink did you mean scale parent too ?

Comment: try my answer below, it is a working example

Comment: @AndroidGeek wait 1 minute while build app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it by scale width and height now parent width and height changed when its child size changed 
`parent.invalidate();`

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:src="@drawable/app_logo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                />

</LinearLayout>
```

Inside your activity set scale of ImageView like this:

```
btnScaleImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                iv_logo.setScaleX(0.5f);
                iv_logo.setScaleY(0.5f);
            }
        });
```

Comment: same while scale its parent height not changed and Image View clipped by parent